# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext crash when using a queue

Tags: ios, core-graphics, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to understand way my code crash when using a queue, but working when using the main thread. This code works fine:

```
- (void)penMoved:(NSSet *)touches {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint midPoint = midpoint(previousPoint, currentPoint);

    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [path addQuadCurveToPoint:midPoint controlPoint:previousPoint];
    [incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [path stroke];

    previousPoint = currentPoint;

    incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

But this version of the code crashes after a while when `incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();` is called.

```
- (void)penMoved:(NSSet *)touches {
    dispatch_async(drawingQueue, ^{
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        CGPoint midPoint = midpoint(previousPoint, currentPoint);

        CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

        [path addQuadCurveToPoint:midPoint controlPoint:previousPoint];
        [incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        [path stroke];

        previousPoint = currentPoint;

        incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    });
}
```

drawingQueue is defined as an ivar like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t drawingQueue;
```

and initialized like this:

```
drawingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("drawingQueue", NULL);
```

Comment: Provide details about the crash.

Comment: I can't.The error only occurs on device and Xcode won't break in the debugger when this happens. It's just crash and Xcode looses the connection.

Comment: You probably want to synchronize access to your `incrementalImage` ivar.

Comment: Ok, I have not idea how to do this in objective c. Any tips?

Comment: Thanks. Just so I understand. I experienced the crash as something that occurred when something got too big, but it was probably more random and crashed when my drawRect was trying to access incrementalImage the same time as penMoved was writing it?

Comment: It's a guess since you can't provide any details about the crash.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about touches. You are talking about a view. Those things are not thread safe. You must not talk about them on a background thread. And you are talking about your `incrementalImage` property on two different threads. And that's just the obvious dangers; there are other properties in there too.

Comment: It's actually documented as perfectly safe to use the `UIGraphincsBegin/EditImageContext` and `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` methods on any thread. It should work in general. The likely issue is that `incrementalImage` is being updated in the background while being accessed on the main thread as the touch events are processed.

Comment: Yes it is, I draw it in drawRect like this: - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [incrementalImage drawInRect:rect];
}

Comment: @rmaddy I didn't say there was anything wrong with the _drawing_ part of the code being on a background thread, did I? My answer pointed to the _other_ stuff. I do background drawing all the time. But I also know something about what else _not_ to do. I am careful not to touch properties on multiple threads, and I never touch anything that isn't thread safe and doesn't belong to me, like a UITouch, on a background thread.